# C++ create objects in the class constructor recursively

Tags: c++, class, recursion

Hi I'm working on my homework and I have a problem here.
I have a class and definition is:

```
class WebNode
{
    private:
        char* m_webAddress;
        char* m_anchorText;
        WebNode** m_hyperlink;
        int m_numOfHyperlinks;

    public:
        // CONSTRUCTOR member function
        WebNode(const char* webAddress, const char* anchorText, int height);
        // DESTRUCTOR member function
        ~WebNode();
        // ACCESSOR member functions
            // not important
};
```

And I'm working on the constructor: `WebNode::WebNode(const char* webAddress, const char* anchorText, int height) {}`. The constructor should firstly setup the private member based on the constructor parameter, then it should recursively create new `WebNode` objects depending on hyperlinks. But I cannot do that because if I use `new WebNode` in the constructor it will say `no matching constructor for initialisation of WebNode`.
So how can I create new objects in the constructor?

Comment: You probably default-construct the new `WebNode` objects inside the constructor? Then you need to have a default-constructor (a constructor which takes no arguments). Without a [mcve] it will be hard to say anything else.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but I'm not allowed to modify the class definition, is there other ways?

Comment: Then you need to construct each and every sub-object using the parameterized constructor you have, by passing the suitable arguments to each and every object creation.

Comment: You ***can*** create new instances inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you create object in the constructor or elsewhere, you need a matching constructor for the call. When you attempt to create an object via

```
new WebNode();
```

then `Webnode` needs a default-constructor (ie one that can be called without parameters).

```
class WebNode
{
    private:
        char* m_webAddress;
        char* m_anchorText;
        WebNode** m_hyperlink;
        int m_numOfHyperlinks;

    public:
        WebNode(const char* webAddress, const char* anchorText, int height);
        WebNode();   // <-----------
        ~WebNode();
};
```

> I'm not allowed to modify the class definition, is there other ways?

Pass the parameters when constructing instances:

```
new WebNode(some_web_address,some_anchor_text,h);
```